# Error Running Ruby on Rails App in Production Mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm just starting to use Ruby on Rails and I am going through a tutorial to get started. I have everything working for testing, so I can use a `rails server` command in the directory to make it show the basic "Welcome aboard" page that I want to see; however, when I change this to `rails server -e production` I suddenly only see the "The page you were looking for doesn't exist." page. When this happens, the command prompt shows:

```
[2013-08-07 19:54:26] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-08-07 19:54:26] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-06-27) [i386-mingw32]
[2013-08-07 19:54:26] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=12664 port=3000
I, [2013-08-07T19:54:26.515238 #12664]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1
at 2013-08-07 19:54:26 -0700
F, [2013-08-07T19:54:26.752394 #12664] FATAL -- :
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `c
all'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `ca  
ll'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tag
ged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `
call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

This may seem very similar to a number of other questions, but I have tried a number of solutions that have all failed. Thank you for any possible help.

Comment: Can you post your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: It actually doesn't have anything but `FirstApp::Application.routes.draw do` and `end` with comments between the two lines.

Comment: run rake:assets:precompile, and try again. What happens?

Comment: @treehau5 No change when I run it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, this is the default behaviour for an application that has no routes.
The "Welcome aboard" page is just an introduction for developers and is only shown in the development environment.

Comment: Oh...well...I probably should have known that. Thank you, though! :)